# com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse class not found

Tags: java, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an application that must authenticate permissions to use specific services from Google (calender, tasks...). I'm using their OAuth2 API. I ran into a run-time exception which is a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" for the class `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse`. I had a similar exception for another class but I solved it by adding the corresponding jar to my project. For this class, however, I cannot find the corresponding jar file. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it present in `libs/google-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc.jar`, which is included in the `google-api-java-client-1.17.0-rc.zip` download here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list